# Correct way to load nested resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In our Rails application we have some fairly deep nested routes. Which has caused some confusion as how to best load resources in the controllers.

For example we might have this setup:

`/clients/:client_id/products/:product_id/builds/:build_id/downloads/:id`

And in our Downloads controller we might have:

```
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :assign_instance_variables

    def index
        @downloads = Download.where(build_id: params[:build_id])
    end

    def show
        @download = Download.find(params[:id])
    end

    private

        def assign_instance_variables
            @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
            @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
            @build = Build.find(params[:build_id])
        end
end
```

However we noticed this actually allows you to change the ID of the download to one from another build and it would still load it fine even though it's not associated because we don't look at the associations...

So we refactored it to do:

```
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :assign_instance_variables

    def index
        @downloads = @build.downloads
    end

    def show
        @download = @build.downloads.find(params[:id])
    end

    private

        def assign_instance_variables
            @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
            @product = @client.products.find(params[:product_id])
            @build = @product.builds.find(params[:build_id])
        end
end
```

Which means that all of the IDs throughout the nesting are checked against the parent object and if any fail it will raise an ActiveRecord::NotFound.

We also thought about doing this:

```
@download = Download.find(params[:id]
@build = @download.build
@product = @build.product
@client = @product.client
```

So we only do one lookup and then follow the chain back up but this then introduces the problem that none of the IDs except the download one are used meaning you could enter anything and the URL would still be considered valid...

What's the correct way to handle getting all the nested resources?

Comment: Do not trust users :) Your first solution is better. Btw, Rails [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) says 'Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.´, go [shallow nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting).

Comment: `introduces the problem that none of the IDs except the download one are used` => I dont really see why you have such nesting in the first place. Why dont just get rid of it then?

Comment: Because the customer wants the data hierarchy as part of the URL. Quite a lot of web apps/sites do this... I don't see an issue with a URL nested like that... Just wondered what people thought was the best way to get/validate the parent associations...

Comment: On devel side, your URL helpers must be quite long and prone to error.